# Rails 5.0.2 incompatibility with bundler 2.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, incompatibility, gem-bundler

I currently am running Rails 5.0.2 with bundler(<2.0, >=1.3.0). This morning when I ran 'gem install bundler', it ended up installing bundler 2.0.1 which is now incompatible with Rails 5.0.2. I'm wondering if I should be upgrading my Rails version or downgrading the bundler version. Please see the log from my jenkins build below.

```
gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-2.0.1
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.0.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 5 seconds
1 gem installed
bundle install
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.0.1)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
```

Comment: do you need anything specific in bundler-2.0.1?

Comment: Nope, don't need anything in 2.0.1

Comment: I would uninstall the bundler, remove the gemlock and install bundler again and bundle install

Answer (score 2):

try

```
gem update --system
```

after

```
bundle install
```

Comment: This worked for me, but some explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Possibly due to Bundler 2 dropped support for RubyGems <3.0 https://bundler.io/blog/2019/01/03/announcing-bundler-2.html